# Does VB6 short-circuit complex conditions?

Tags: vb6

Does VB6 short circuit conditional tests? That is to say, can I be sure a statement like...

```
If index <= array_size And array(index) > something Then
```

will never burst the array, whatever the value of index might happen to be?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, VB6's `And` and `Or` don't short-circuit (which is the reason why the short-circuit versions are called `AndAlso` and `OrElse` in VB.net — backward compatibility).

Comment: I had no idea VB.NET supported this!  Thanks so much for this enlightening answer.  You have saved me many nested `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you, KennyTM. You have doubtless saved me many exploding arrays.

Comment: this question might be 12 years late but.... why would you need to (in any regard) have a version of these operations that can't short-circuit for backwards compatibility?  I can't think of a single reason why it is this way what so ever.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `If/Then/Else/End If` block, VB6 also supports a single-line `If/Then/Else` construct. You can nest these to achieve simple short-circuiting. However, since it's a single-line statement, you must perform your desired action on the same line as well. For example:

```
' From (no short-circuit)
If index <= array_size And array(index) > something Then

' To (short-circuit)
If index <= array_size Then If array(index) > something Then ...
```

Comment: So `AndAlso` in VB.Net is `Then If` in VB6. You can use line continuation (underscore) at will too.

Comment: @wqw, Yep, line continuation can be used. However you can't have a block of statements after the single-line `Then`. If you need to perform multiple operations, it's necessary to use `:` to separate them.

Comment: Wherever in VB6 you can use `And`, in VB.Net you can use `AndAlso` to short-circuit the expression. What I mean is that in `If` statement in VB6 wherever you can use `And` you can use `Then If` (treat it like a single bool opertator though it is not) to short-circuit the expression.

Comment: Right, I understand what you're saying. I'm just trying to explain the *downfall* of using the single-line `If/Then/Else` and that is that you cannot specify more than one operation to be performed (without using `:`). So if you have a huge block of code to be executed, using a single-line `If/Then/Else` might not be an option, unless you can move that block of code to a subroutine and make a single call to it.

Comment: You are right. This is a severe limitation of the `Then If` hack.

Comment: `Then If` is no different then using nested `If`statements.  There's no need to keep them all on one line or to use the `:` to put other code on the same line.  Just hit the enter key and nest the code with proper indentation to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

Select Case is a short circuit method if you can use it for your purpose.

Comment: I don't think I can, but thank you for the suggestion anyway.