# Complex IF THEN statements in VB6

Tags: vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does VB6 short-circuit complex conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014918/does-vb6-short-circuit-complex-conditions)

I am curious about how IF statements are executed in VB6.
For example if I have the statement

```
If x And y Then
    'execute some code
End If
```

Does the code move on if `x` is not true? Or does it go ahead and evaluate `y` even though there is no logical point?

Another example

```
If x Or y Then
    'execute some code
End If
```

Does the code continue and evaluate `y` if `x` is true?

EDIT:
Is there a way to avoid nested `IF` statements if I want to evaluate very complex conditions and I don't want to waste CPU time?

Comment: No, vb 6 does not have short circuit logic. Execution continues.

Comment: No, my question is about alternatives to nested `IF` statements. see the EDIT.

Comment: That's a different story.  Provided an answer on how to do this efficiently.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the other question, and the answers to the other are nothing like what I am looking for? Who makes these calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unwieldy or-like statement that exhibits short circuiting behaviour:

```
select case True
   case a(), b(), c()
      '//if a returns true b & c are not invoked, if b returns true a & b were invoked
   case else
      ...
```

Comment: Unreadable! If I find myself maintaining this code because its "better than nested ifs", well, I'm [coming after you](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/coding-for-violent-psychopaths.html)

Comment: That is still better thah 
If a() Then
  If b() Then
    If c() Then

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is short circuiting logic, and VB6 doesn't have it...

For example, in VB.Net you might write

```
If x AndAlso y then...
```

In this case `y` is not tested if `x` turns out to be false.

In your VB6 example, you'll get a `Object or With block variable not set` error if you try something such as:

```
Dim x as Object
If Not x Is Nothing And x.y=1 Then
```

Since object x has not been instantiated.

Comment: Not a VB6 guy, but it sounds like Jon has it right.  You can verify it by doing something like if FunctionA() and FunctionB(), and then define Function A and B both to print a debug message and return false.  Then see who you get debug messages from.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: No - the `AndAlso`/`OrElse` operators only exist in VB.NET, not VB6.

Comment: @RBarryYoung To avoid future confusion, can you delete your comments please?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your edit - avoiding nested IF statements, you can use Select Case, covered in the latter half of [this article](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/learn-if-else-and-select-statements-vb6).

Code snippet from the article:

```
Select Case strShiftCode
   Case "1" 
      sngShiftRate = sngHourlyRate
   Case "2" 
      sngShiftRate = sngHourlyRate * 1.1
   Case "3"
      sngShiftRate = sngHourlyRate * 1.5
   Case Else
      Print "Shift Code Error"
End Select
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was thinking as well.. Thank you for the answer.